# Как убрать полоску сверху в QTabWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qtabwidget

Нужно убрать полоску (над вкладками **`Finder`** и **`Settings`**), которая точно относится к классу `QTabWidget`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот использованные стили:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
QTabBar::tab {  
    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);
}

QTabBar::tab:hover {
    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background: rgb(129, 135, 255);
    color: rgb(248, 246, 255);
    border: 2px solid rgb(129, 135, 255);
}

QTabWidget::pane{
    border: 1px;
    background: rgb(129, 135, 255);
}
```

Полный код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'D:\программирование\python projects\My projects\FindEnderPortal-versions\FindEnderPortal-1.3\design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(440, 520)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(440, 520))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/Ender_eye.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    margin-left: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTabBar::tab:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTabBar::tab:selected {\n"
"    background: rgb(129, 135, 255);\n"
"    color: rgb(248, 246, 255);\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(129, 135, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTabWidget::pane{\n"
"    border: 1px;\n"
"    background: rgb(129, 135, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabWidget.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabBarAutoHide(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.tab.setFont(font)
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.first_eye = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.first_eye.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.first_eye.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.first_eye.setFont(font)
        self.first_eye.setObjectName("first_eye")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.first_eye)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.tab)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.checkBox.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox.setStyleSheet(" QCheckBox {\n"
"     spacing: 5px;\n"
" }\n"
"\n"
" QCheckBox::indicator {\n"
"     width: 13px;\n"
"     height: 13px;\n"
" }")
        self.checkBox.setCheckable(True)
        self.checkBox.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.x1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.x1.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.x1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.x1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.x1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.x1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.x1.setFont(font)
        self.x1.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit:focus {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.x1.setText("")
        self.x1.setFrame(False)
        self.x1.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.x1.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
        self.x1.setObjectName("x1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.x1)
        self.z1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.z1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.z1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.z1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.z1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.z1.setFont(font)
        self.z1.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit:focus {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.z1.setText("")
        self.z1.setFrame(False)
        self.z1.setObjectName("z1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.z1)
        self.alpha = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.alpha.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.alpha.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.alpha.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.alpha.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.alpha.setFont(font)
        self.alpha.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit:focus {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.alpha.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.alpha.setText("")
        self.alpha.setFrame(False)
        self.alpha.setObjectName("alpha")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.alpha)
        self.second_eye = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.second_eye.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.second_eye.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.second_eye.setFont(font)
        self.second_eye.setObjectName("second_eye")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.second_eye)
        self.x2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.x2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.x2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.x2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.x2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.x2.setFont(font)
        self.x2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit:focus {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.x2.setText("")
        self.x2.setFrame(False)
        self.x2.setObjectName("x2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.x2)
        self.z2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.z2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.z2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.z2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.z2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.z2.setFont(font)
        self.z2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit:focus {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.z2.setText("")
        self.z2.setFrame(False)
        self.z2.setObjectName("z2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.z2)
        self.beta = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.beta.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.beta.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.beta.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.beta.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.beta.setFont(font)
        self.beta.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit:focus {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.beta.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.beta.setText("")
        self.beta.setFrame(False)
        self.beta.setObjectName("beta")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.beta)
        self.label_coordinates = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_coordinates.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.label_coordinates.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label_coordinates.setFont(font)
        self.label_coordinates.setObjectName("label_coordinates")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_coordinates)
        self.x0 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.x0.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.x0.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.x0.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.x0.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.x0.setFont(font)
        self.x0.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit:focus {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.x0.setText("")
        self.x0.setFrame(False)
        self.x0.setReadOnly(True)
        self.x0.setObjectName("x0")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.x0)
        self.z0 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.z0.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.z0.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.z0.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.z0.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.z0.setFont(font)
        self.z0.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit:focus {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.z0.setText("")
        self.z0.setFrame(False)
        self.z0.setReadOnly(True)
        self.z0.setObjectName("z0")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.z0)
        self.btn_command = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_command.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_command.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_command.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.btn_command.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.btn_command.setFont(font)
        self.btn_command.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(129, 135, 255);\n"
"    color: rgb(248, 246, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(115, 115, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(116, 98, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.btn_command.setObjectName("btn_command")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_command)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.tab_2.setFont(font)
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout_6.setObjectName("gridLayout_6")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.hotkey2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.hotkey2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.hotkey2.setFont(font)
        self.hotkey2.setObjectName("hotkey2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.hotkey2, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_auto_mode = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_auto_mode.setFont(font)
        self.label_auto_mode.setObjectName("label_auto_mode")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_auto_mode, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        self.Label_hotkey1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.Label_hotkey1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.Label_hotkey1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.Label_hotkey1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.Label_hotkey1.setFont(font)
        self.Label_hotkey1.setStyleSheet("QLabel {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLabel:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.Label_hotkey1.setObjectName("Label_hotkey1")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.Label_hotkey1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_hotkey2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_hotkey2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_hotkey2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_hotkey2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label_hotkey2.setFont(font)
        self.label_hotkey2.setStyleSheet("QLabel {    \n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QLabel:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.label_hotkey2.setObjectName("label_hotkey2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_hotkey2, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_language = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_language.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label_language.setFont(font)
        self.label_language.setObjectName("label_language")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_language, 4, 1, 1, 2)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        self.comboBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet(" QComboBox {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
" }\n"
"\n"
"QComboBox:hover {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QComboBox:focus {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QComboBox::drop-down \n"
"{\n"
"    width: 0px;\n"
"    height: 0px;\n"
"    border: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QComboBox QAbstractItemView {\n"
"    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);\n"
"    padding: 10px;\n"
"      border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    selection-background-color: rgb(140, 146, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBox, 5, 1, 1, 2)
        self.hotkey1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.hotkey1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.hotkey1.setFont(font)
        self.hotkey1.setObjectName("hotkey1")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.hotkey1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3)
        self.gridLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_7.setObjectName("gridLayout_7")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.tab_2)
        self.textBrowser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 700))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.textBrowser.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet(" QTextBrowser {\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    padding-left: 5px;\n"
"    padding-right: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
" }")
        self.textBrowser.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.gridLayout_7.addWidget(self.textBrowser, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout_7)
        self.gridLayout_6.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "FindEnderPortal"))
        self.first_eye.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1st eye of ender"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto mode"))
        self.x1.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "x:"))
        self.z1.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "z:"))
        self.alpha.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "angle:"))
        self.second_eye.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2nd eye of ender"))
        self.x2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "x:"))
        self.z2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "z:"))
        self.beta.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "angle:"))
        self.label_coordinates.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Portal coordinates"))
        self.x0.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "x:"))
        self.z0.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "z:"))
        self.btn_command.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Copy command with coordinates"))
        self.btn_command.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Return"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Finder"))
        self.hotkey2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hotkey for second trow"))
        self.label_auto_mode.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto mode"))
        self.Label_hotkey1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "v"))
        self.label_hotkey2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "b"))
        self.label_language.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Language"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "English"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Русский"))
        self.hotkey1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hotkey for first trow"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:13pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">How to use this program:</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">[in procces...]</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update**:

Но я сомневаюсь, что это поможет, так как на моем компьютере уже конвертированный в питон файл не показывает эту полосу, а на другом компьютере показывает. 
Возможно это из за того что у меня *Windows 11*, а на другом была *Windows 10*.

Comment: отвечать вам также будут фотографиями

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Никогда не публикуйте обычный текст в виде картинки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ваш вариант:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Это вариант если убрать строку:

```
self.tabWidget.setDocumentMode(True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]